# Getting an A-record to point to an URL as opposed to an IPv4 address in Route 53 settings

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have configured the following:

1. A web host using Amazon EC2, created an instance running Ubuntu and wordpress; I have an address for my home page x.x.x.x/wordpress/
2. DNS service using Amazon Route 53, with a zone created and a list of 4 ns server addresses (as expected).
3. A domain from domain.com

The issue I have is that when I create an A record in Route 53, I have no choice but to input only the IPv4 address of the server (x.x.x.x) without the "/wordpress/" section, meaning that when someone goes to my URL (xyz.com), they are presented with the backend of the wordpress showing buttons for "Open my Application" and "Go to MyPHP", etc.

I cannot get the DNS service to point to the "x.x.x.x/wordpress" in order to get to the actual homepage.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

DNS wont actually do this. You need to change the document root within your web server settings to set the root to be within the wordpress folder.

Wordpress has some base url settings in the wp_options table that may also need to be changed.

Comment: Would I find the wp_options table in the phpMyAdmin? Or by logging in by SSH?

Comment: However you access your mysql server. If that is you use phpmyadmin for that, then that is where you will be able to change the options.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the "siteurl" from http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/ to http://127.0.0.1/ and it hasn't made any difference. What should I try next?

Comment: Read the answer again: "document root within your web server settings."  Not Wordpress, not MySQL... the web server.  Possibly, depending on many factors, this is the setting of `DocumentRoot` in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default, after which, you'll need to reload the apache web server config.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution eventually...

First, `cd` into the directory where the `.pem` key is kept.

Then, (using Mac OSX Terminal in my case) SSH into the bitnami using the following command:

```
ssh -i myrslkey.pem bitnami@[instance elastic IP]
```

Once logged in, using the following command to change the ULR from [Domain].com/wordpress/ to [Domain].com/  :

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bnconfig --appurl /
```

Use this command litterally; **don't** change "appurl" to your own URL or anything like that, because "appurl" is the **command name**. Simply use that command as it is and it will work.